# can't work with retrieved mongo data in Nestjs because of TS type problem

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, asynchronous, nestjs

I have a problem when working with the records in my Nestjs Services or Repositories after retrieving data from a model (no matter what model). Imagine I want to find a **User** by its **ID** from my Mongo database. Here is what I implemented:

**User.service:**

```
  async findOne<User>(
    data: UserPartialType,
    serviceOptions?: ServiceOptionsDto,
  ): Promise<User> {
    const result: User = await this.userRepository.findOne<User>(
      data,
      serviceOptions,
    );

    return result;
  }
```

I can not work with `result` properties here. After trying something like `result._id` or `result.name` I get this error:

> Property '_id' does not exist on type 'User'.ts

Worth mentioning that type of `result` after response is `Awaited<User>` not `User`

And here is how I implemented my repositories:

**User.repository:**

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersRepository extends BaseRepository {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(User.name) private readonly userModel: Model<UserDocument>,
  ) {
    super(userModel);
  }

  async findOne<User>(
    data?: UserPartialType,
    options?: RepositoryOptionsDto,
  ): Promise<User> {
    const result = await this.baseFindOne<User>(data as Partial<User>, options);
    return result;
  }
}
```

I have the same problem as my service here. Type of `result` is `Awaited<User>` that I think because of this TS does not let me use it.

And this is my abstract base repository:

**base.repository:**

```
export abstract class BaseRepository {
  private model: Model<unknown>;
  constructor(model: Model<unknown>) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  protected async baseFindOne<T>(
    data: Partial<T> | Record<string, any>,
    options?: RepositoryOptionsDto,
  ): Promise<T> {
    // ENSURE INCOMING DATA
    data = data ?? {};

    // DEFINE QUERY
    let query = {};

    if (data.id) {
      query['_id'] = this.convertToObjectId(data.id);
      delete data.id;
    }

    query = {
      ...query,
      ...data,
      deletedAt: null,
    };

    // SEARCH AND RETURN DATA
    return (await this.model.findOne(query))?.toObject();
  }
}
```

Comment: How is type User defined?